# generate dictionaries based on condition from a data frame column

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

am trying to subset a dataset based on a condition and pick the rows until it sees the value based on a condition.

Dataset:

```
A   B
0   aa
1   ss
2   dd
0   ee
1   ff
2   bb
3   gg
0   ar
1   hh
2   ww
0   jj
1   ll
```

Output expected:

```
[{'A':[0,1,2], 'B':['aa','ss','dd']},{'A':[0,1,2,3], 'B':['ee','ff','bb','gg']},  {'A':[0,1,2], 'B':['ar','hh,'ww']} , {'A': [0,1], 'B': ['jj','ll']}]
```

Condition: The series starts from column A == 0 and ends until the next 0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can `groupby` then [`GroupBy.agg`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.agg.html) to `list` then use [`df.to_dict`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_dict.html) with orient as `records`

```
g = df['A'].eq(0).cumsum()
df.groupby(g).agg(list).to_dict(orient='records')

[{'A': [0, 1, 2], 'B': ['aa', 'ss', 'dd']},
 {'A': [0, 1, 2, 3], 'B': ['ee', 'ff', 'bb', 'gg']},
 {'A': [0, 1, 2], 'B': ['ar', 'hh', 'ww']},
 {'A': [0, 1], 'B': ['jj', 'll']}]
```

Comment: can you make me undeerstand about cumsum()  here ?

Comment: @pylearner Where there `0` in column `A` is marked as `True` which is `1` and `False` is `0` e.g. `[True, False, False, True, False]` cumsum of this would be `[1, 1, 1, 2, 2]`

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
groups = np.cumsum(df.A == 0)

sol = []
for name, group in df.groupby(groups):
    sol.append(group.to_dict(orient="list"))
```

or, if you prefer `apply`:

```
sol2 = []
df.groupby(groups).apply(lambda x: sol2.append(x.to_dict(orient="list")))
```

result:

```
[{'A': [0, 1, 2], 'B': ['aa', 'ss', 'dd']}, {'A': [0, 1, 2, 3], 'B': ['ee', 'ff', 'bb', 'gg']}, {'A': [0, 1, 2], 'B': ['ar', 'hh', 'ww']}, {'A': [0, 1], 'B': ['jj', 'll']}]
```

A few notes: you can groupby `groups` even though it is not a column in your `df` (has to be like-indexed I think).  I prefer the for-loop, since I tend to think of apply as an operation on the dataframe, whereas your operation leaves the df untouched but creates a list.